# What does a "*" at the start of a regular expression do?

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression, posix

In this case discussed:
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11
grep (GNU grep) 2.20

Let's say I have a directory that contains a bunch of files. I want to find the files named jtobdops02.key and jtobdops.02.cer.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*jtobdops02\.(key|cer)"
```

Gives:

**./certs/jtobdops02.key**

**./certs/jtobdops02.cer**

```
find . -type f | grep -E '.*jtobdops02.*(key|cer)'
```

Also gives as expected:

**./certs/jtobdops02.key**

**./certs/jtobdops02.cer**

Yet

```
find . -type f | grep -E '*jtobdops02.*(key|cer)'
```

Gives this:

./certs/**jtobdops02.key**

./certs/**jtobdops02.cer**

The man for find states:

```
This is a match on the whole path, not a search.
```

The man for grep states:

```
grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern
```

If they both do matching, not search, why does the latter grep still work? Also in the latter case there is no preceding sub expression for grep to match, so what does the `*` match in this case? The colored(bold) output shows no difference, so I assume it does nothing. Shouldn't it give error in this case?

Which one of those is idiosyncrasy and which one of those is a general practice across other tools and languages?

Comment: The first `*` is meaningless so the expression is equivalent to `'jtobdops02.*(key|cer)'`

Comment: Yes, it can be argued that a regular expression beginning with `*` should result in an error.  Maybe they thought it was more user-friendly just to ignore the `*`.

Answer (score 2):

An extended regular expression starting with an `*` will produce *an undefined result*, according to [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

This is with `grep` on OpenBSD 6.4:

```
$ grep -E '*hello'
grep: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

GNU `grep` seems to ignore the `*` altogether:

```
$ printf 'hello\n' | ggrep -E '*hello'
hello
```

According to [the same standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), if using basic regular expressions (`grep` without `-E`), an `*` at the start of an expression or subexpression inside `\(...\)` (or right after an initial `^`) is to be *interpreted as a literal `*`*.

Comment: `ggrep`'s `'*hello'` is probably interpreted as `<nothing>*hello` (any number of nothing). `echo xfoo | ggrep -E '^*foo'` (or `'^?foo'`) seems to match but with zero-width somewhere. Neither `echo xfoofoo | ggrep -E '(^*foo)\1'` nor `echo xfooxfoo | ggrep -E '(^*foo)\1?'` match. Seems buggy.